# .Subscribe() function receiving value but unable to enter the function block

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, observable, angular7

Call a service from springboot backend fromfront end using rxjs observable. Even thought using a .subscribe function to call this service ,which is successfully returning a value , i am unable to enter the subscribe block , it directly reaches the end of the block.

login.component.ts

```
validate() {
    console.log('need to validate');
    this.loginService.checkLogin(this.userName, this.pwd).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      if (resp === 'success') {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      }
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error(error.error.message);
    });
  }
```

login.service.ts

```
export class LoginServiceService {

  url = 'http://localhost:8089/login/check';
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

   public checkLogin(userName, password): Observable <any> {
    let headersValue = new HttpHeaders();
    headersValue = headersValue.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headersValue = headersValue.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headersValue = headersValue.set('userName', userName);
    headersValue = headersValue.set('password', password);
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url, { headers: headersValue });
}
}
```

expected result : it should enter subscribe block and display resp in console and also enter if block.

actual result :
only "need to validate is displayed".

and directly reaches the end of block after error  check .

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may have to do with the headers. I am not sure if you need any of them, but more specifically I don't think userName and password belong there at all.  They should probably be params. I think the following may help you:

```
public checkLogin(userName, password): Observable <any> {
    let headersValue = new HttpHeaders();
    headersValue = headersValue.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headersValue = headersValue.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const params = { userName, password };
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url, { headers: headersValue, params });
}
```

Comment: I am able to return value don't have any issue with the headers or params. The value is returned from login.service.ts to login.component.ts but it doesn't enter the subscribe block